# Injective edge choice functions in linear hypergraphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-colorings, hypergraph

A *linear hypergraph* is a [hypergraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergraph) $H=(V,E)$ such that

1. for $e\in E$ we have $|e|\geq 2$, and
2. if $e\neq e_1\in E$, then $|e\cap e_1| \leq 1$.

An *injective edge choice function* of a linear hypergraph is an injective map $f:E\to V$ such that:

> for all $e\in E$ we have $f(e)\in e$.

Obviously, if $|E|>|V|$ there cannot be such a function.

**Question.** If $H=(V,E)$ is a linear hypergraph with $V$ finite and $|e|\geq 3$ for all $e\in E$, does $H$ necessarily have an injective edge choice function?

Comment: Maybe I misread something, but does 2. hold if $e\cap e_1=\emptyset$ anyway? So the question is if $H$ has a set of distinct representatives.Surely it does not, if $|E|>|V|$.

Comment: You are right @PéterKomjáth! I should formulate this in a more elegant way. - An interesting subquestion is whether $|e|>2$ for all $e\in E$ implies $|E|\leq |V|$?

Comment: No, there's an [affine plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_plane_(incidence_geometry)#Finite_affine_planes) on 9 points with 12 lines, and every line has length 3.

Comment: Thanks - can you post this as an answer such that we can close this thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even $|E|\leq|V|$ does not hold: An [affine plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_plane_(incidence_geometry)#Finite_affine_planes) contains more lines than points.